# How to use a variable in reading a filepath?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to simplify the code instead of changing a bunch of variables.

For example:

```
title = "example"
filepath = r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Research\title"
```

I want the output to be `C:\Users\User\Desktop\Research\example`, but it returns the quoted string.

How would I make it read the "title" variable instead?

Answer (score 1):

Use a formatting string along with your raw string.

```
title = "example"
filepath = rf"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Research\{title}"
```

Output:

```
>>> print(filepath)
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Research\example
>>>
```